# Vertically center text on an image - dynamically

Tags: html, css

I have images and a text that is displayed in the center of the image when somebody is hovering over the image.

HTML looks like this:

```
<article>
<div class="entry-content">
<a href="http://www.linktopost.com">
<h3 class="entry-title">Ring #1</h3>
<img width="620" height="387" src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02725/scotch-whisky_2725818b.jpg" class="aligncenter" alt="Platzhalter_3">
</a>
</div>
</article>
```

CSS:

```
article {
  float:left;
  width:30%;
  display:block;
}

.entry-content {
  width: 620px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  height: 387px;
}

.entry-content:hover .entry-title {
  color: #000;
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: #fff;
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.entry-title {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  line-height: 387px;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

article img {
  position:absolute;
}
```

You can see it here:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rOXOez

Is there any chance to not use fixed pixel values in the CSS - so that the hover effect is valid and working for any picture? In this example I had to use the width and height of the picture in the CSS to achieve what I wanted.

Thank you!

Comment: you could use flex... it is best modern way to do it ;) google flex align middle

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1:**

Relative/Absolute positioning and center with `transform: translate()`

https://jsfiddle.net/94efk8kz/

```
article {
  position: relative;
}

.hover-content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.hover-content h3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

**Solution 2**:

Flexbox

https://jsfiddle.net/94efk8kz/1/

```
article {
  position: relative;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.hover-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

**Solution 3**

CSS Tables

https://jsfiddle.net/94efk8kz/2/

```
.entry-content  a {
  float: left;
  width:30%;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}


.hover-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  opacity: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}


.v-align {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.hover-content h3 {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: That's the real best solution because you use `transform: translate()`. Problems: You are not explaining your answer, so OP doesn't know how do you are talking about. Second problem is compatibility. With your code, in iOS doesn't works, or in older browsers like IE9/10. You need to add `-webkit-transform` and `-ms-transform`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with these changes

```
.entry-content {
  width: initial;
}
.entry-content:hover .entry-title {
  margin: 0;
}
.article img {
  display: block;
  /* position: absolute; remove this,avoid using positon absolute where you can */

  width: 100%;
}
```